# Pygame - Alien Invasion; How to adjust my fleets starting position?

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

I'm struggling with adjusting my game so that my fleet of aliens doesn't start out under my top UI. I know this has something to do with adjusting my first generation of my alien, before I create the fleet, but I'm pretty new to coding in general and am just not quite sure what I need to adjust.

This game as made while following along with Python Crash Course 2nd Edition.

[As you can see, my fleet sits under my ship UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuHBA.png)

[Adjust some code to render Aliens ontop of UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZNyc.jpg)

This suggestion, puts my aliens over top of my UI, which I guess is better, but I my opinion still does not look good.

alien_invasion.py

```
def __init__(self):
    """Initlize the game, and create game resources."""
    pygame.init()
    self.settings = Settings()
    self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((
        self.settings.screen_width, self.settings.screen_height
    ))
    self.settings.screen_width = self.screen.get_rect().width
    self.settings.screen_height = self.screen.get_rect().height

    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

    self.stats = GameStats(self)
    self.sb = Scoreboard(self)

    self.ship = Ship(self)

    self.bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()

    self.aliens = pygame.sprite.Group()
    self._create_fleet()

    #Set our background color
    self.bg_color = (230, 230, 230)
    
    self.play_button = Button(self, "Play")

def run_game(self):
    """Start main loop for our game."""
    while True:
        self._check_events()

        if self.stats.game_active:
            self.ship.update()
            self._update_bullets()
            self._update_aliens()
            
        self._update_screen()

def _check_events(self):
    """Respond to kepresses and mouse events."""
    #for each event in game capture that event
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        #if player preses close, quit game
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        # if event is a key press
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            self._check_keydown_events(event)
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            self._check_keyup_events(event)
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            self._check_play_button(mouse_pos)

def _check_play_button(self, mouse_pos):
    """start new game if player clicks play"""
    button_clicked = self.play_button.rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos)
    if button_clicked and not self.stats.game_active:
        self.settings.initialize_dynamic_settings()
        self.stats.reset_stats()
        self.stats.game_active = True
        self.sb.prep_score()
        self.sb.prep_level()
        self.sb.prep_ships()

        self.aliens.empty()
        self.bullets.empty()

        self._create_fleet()
        self.ship.center_ship()

        pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)

def _check_keydown_events(self, event):
    """respond to keydown events"""
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        self.ship.moving_right = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        self.ship.moving_left = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
        sys.exit()
    elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
        self._fire_bullet()

def _check_keyup_events(self, event):
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        self.ship.moving_right = False
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        self.ship.moving_left = False

def _fire_bullet(self):
    """create a new bullet and add it to the bullets group"""
    if len(self.bullets) < self.settings.bullets_allowed:
        new_bullet = Bullet(self)
        # add is simpler than append, but is only avaliable in pygame
        self.bullets.add(new_bullet)
        
def _update_bullets(self):
    """update bullets position and get rid of old bullets"""
    #update bullets position
    self.bullets.update()
    # get rid of bullets that leave the window
    for bullet in self.bullets.copy():
        if bullet.rect.bottom <= 0:
            self.bullets.remove(bullet)

    self._check_bullet_alien_collisions()

def _check_bullet_alien_collisions(self):
    """respond to bullet-alien collisions"""
    collisions = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(
        self.bullets, self.aliens, False, True
    )

    if collisions:
        for aliens in collisions.values():
            self.stats.score += self.settings.alien_points * len(aliens)
        self.sb.prep_score()
        self.sb.check_high_score()

    if not self.aliens:
        self.bullets.empty()
        self._create_fleet()
        self.settings.increse_speed()

        self.stats.level += 1
        self.sb.prep_level()

def _update_aliens(self):
    """update the position of the aliens"""
    self._check_fleet_edges()
    self.aliens.update()

    # look for alien ship collisions
    if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(self.ship, self.aliens):
        self._ship_hit()

    self._check_aliens_bottom()

def _ship_hit(self):
    """respond to the ship being hit by alien"""
    if self.stats.ships_left > 0:
        # decrese ships left
        self.stats.ships_left -= 1
        self.sb.prep_ships()

        # get rid of any remaining aliens and bullets
        self.aliens.empty()
        self.bullets.empty()

        # create new fleet and recenter ship
        self._create_fleet()
        self.ship.center_ship()
    
        # small pause for reset
        sleep(0.5)
    else:
        self.stats.game_active = False
        pygame.mouse.set_visible(True)

def _create_fleet(self):
    """create our fleet of aliens"""
    # creat an alien and fine the number that fits in a row
    # spacing between each alien is equal to one alien
    alien = Alien(self)
    alien_width, alien_height = alien.rect.size
    available_space_x = self.settings.screen_width - (2 * alien_width)
    number_aliens_x = available_space_x // (2 * alien_width)

    # determine the number of rows that fit on the screen
    ship_height = self.ship.rect.height
    available_space_y = (self.settings.screen_height - 
                            (3 * alien_height) - ship_height)
    number_rows = available_space_y // (2 * alien_height)

    # create a full fleet of aliens
    for row_number in range(number_rows):
        for alien_number in range(number_aliens_x):
            self._create_alien(alien_number, row_number)

def _create_alien(self, alien_number, row_number):
    alien = Alien(self)
    alien_width, alien_height = alien.rect.size
    alien.x = alien_width + 2 * alien_width * alien_number
    alien.rect.x = alien.x
    alien.rect.y = alien_height + 2 * alien.rect.height * row_number
    self.aliens.add(alien)

def _check_fleet_edges(self):
    """respond if any aliens reach the edge"""
    for alien in self.aliens.sprites():
        if alien.check_edges():
            self._change_fleet_direction()
            break

def _check_aliens_bottom(self):
    """check if any aliens have reached the bottom of the screen"""
    screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()
    for alien in self.aliens.sprites():
        if alien.rect.bottom >= screen_rect.bottom:
            self._ship_hit()
            break

def _change_fleet_direction(self):
    """drop entire fleet and change direction"""
    for alien in self.aliens.sprites():
        alien.rect.y += self.settings.fleet_drop_speed
    self.settings.fleet_direction *= -1

def _update_screen(self):
    """Update images on screen and flip to the new screen."""
    #fill our background with our bg_color
    self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)
    #draw ship to screen
    self.ship.blitme()

    for bullet in self.bullets.sprites():
        bullet.draw_bullet()
        
    # draw scoreboard to screen
    self.sb.show_score()

    self.aliens.draw(self.screen)



    # draw play button if game is inactive
    if not self.stats.game_active:
        self.play_button.draw_button()

    #Make the most recently drawn screen visible.
    #this clears our previous screen and updates it to a new one
    #this gives our programe smooth movemnt
    pygame.display.flip()
```

alien.py

```
def __init__(self, ai_game):
    """initlize alien and set its starting position"""
    super().__init__()
    self.screen = ai_game.screen
    self.settings = ai_game.settings
    self.screen_rect = ai_game.screen.get_rect()

    # load alien image at set its rect
    self.image = pygame.image.load('images/alien.bmp')
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    # start each new alien at the top left of the screen
    self.rect.x = self.rect.width
    self.rect.y = self.rect.height

    # store aliens exact position (decimal)
    self.x = float(self.rect.x)

def check_edges(self):
    """return true if alien is at edge of screen"""
    screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()
    if self.rect.right >= screen_rect.right or self.rect.left <= 0:
        return True

def update(self):
    """move the alien to the right or left"""
    self.x += (self.settings.alien_speed *
                    self.settings.fleet_direction)
    self.rect.x = self.x
```

I'm looking to draw my first alien to screen further down the screen so that it does not interfere with my UI at all.

To my understanding this is an issue with where the first alien is being drawn to screen.

```py
self.rect.x = self.rect.width
self.rect.y = self.rect.height
```

This should be giving the first alien the space of one alien to the left and to the top of the alien, but when I adjust self.rect.y in any way, nothing actually changes in the way the aliens are drawn to screen.

Any help on understanding this concept more would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Things you render later are rendered on top of the ones before. Move your ui drawing code before your fleet drawing code. That way, It will draw the ui first and draw the fleet on top of it. You probably have it the other way round right now.

Comment: Well, you were correct about my UI being drawn before my fleet, adjusting that does move the fleet ONTOP of the UI, but I don't want my fleet to interfere with my UI in any way.

Comment: Hi, I'm the author of PCC and I just wanted to compliment your game's styling. I've seen a lot of variations of the game, and this is one of the most visually appealing versions I've seen. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adapt the code in the `_create_fleet` and `_create_alien` methods of your first class to account for the space being taken up at the top of the screen by the UI. I don't know exactly what size you want there, but I'll point out where to put it in the code below:

```
def _create_fleet(self):
    """create our fleet of aliens"""
    # creat an alien and fine the number that fits in a row
    # spacing between each alien is equal to one alien
    alien = Alien(self)
    alien_width, alien_height = alien.rect.size
    available_space_x = self.settings.screen_width - (2 * alien_width)
    number_aliens_x = available_space_x // (2 * alien_width)

    # determine the number of rows that fit on the screen
    ship_height = self.ship.rect.height
    available_space_y = (self.settings.screen_height -          # substract UI height here
                            (3 * alien_height) - ship_height)
    number_rows = available_space_y // (2 * alien_height)

    # create a full fleet of aliens
    for row_number in range(number_rows):
        for alien_number in range(number_aliens_x):
            self._create_alien(alien_number, row_number)

def _create_alien(self, alien_number, row_number):
    alien = Alien(self)
    alien_width, alien_height = alien.rect.size
    alien.x = alien_width + 2 * alien_width * alien_number
    alien.rect.x = alien.x
    alien.rect.y = alien_height + 2 * alien.rect.height * row_number  # add UI height here
    self.aliens.add(alien)
```

Comment: That makes total sense! I was able to subtract an extra 'alien height' in create fleet and add 2 extra 'alien heights' at create_alien. Its beautiful, thank you!